# URL rewriting asp.net IIS

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, iis-7

I'm trying to rewrite the URL in IIS URL rewriter module.

I've to convert the following url:

```
websitename/Pages/Products.aspx?Category=10-Dishwashers
```

to

```
websitename/pages/products/category/dishwashers
```

I've tried something like this:

^Pages/Products.aspx?Category=10 (REGEX)

action: pages/product/category/diswashers

I'm new to this. I don't know how to proceed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about the reverse, in other words from having a nice clean URL (no query string), to get back to the one that includes the "id" in the query string, so that your customers don't need to see that numeric ID.

If that is the case, then what I would recommend is using a rewriteMap where you can have that mapping and then you can have friendly names for the categories and resolve to whatever numeric ID is, for example if you add the below in a web.config it will match the nice URL and transform it into the .aspx?Category format :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteCategory">
                    <match url="pages/products/category/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="pages/products.aspx?Category={CategoryMap:{R:1}}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="CategoryMap" defaultValue="other">
                    <add key="dishwashers" value="10-Dishwashers" />
                    <add key="something" value="20-s" />
                    <add key="anotherkey" value="30-another" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```